# Rails / image not being saved when Carrierwave is mounted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, carrierwave, rails-engines

I am using the Carrierwave plugin to upload images. It works fine, but if I try to save an image from the controller using

```
Article.create(:image => 'sample.png')
```

It doesent save the image as long as carrierwave is mounted, if I un-mount Rails will save the image like normal.. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it, and it works in my seeds at least :

```
Article.create(:image => File.open(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "sample.png"))
```

As you can see, make sure to provide the full path to the file. Explicitly opening the file may help too.